# fading out displacement?

Tags: modeling

As you can see I am making a backdrop and halfway up the curve between the ground and the wall I want the water droplets to bland with the solid color wall. Like a gradient mix. I assumed I could just mix the wall and the water droplet ground together in the middle, but when I use the mix shader, you can see it just makes it 50% of each material. I'm looking for a way to mix in the middle and fade from one material to the other. If you view it from the front, you can see the harsh divide between the water drop ground then the face with the mix shader above that, and then it's the solid color wall.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I wanted to check what it looks like if I rendered it, and this is how it turned out. It looks nothing like the image above when I used the render view. I think there is something I'm doing wrong with the materials on the backdrop.

[image]

now I have discovered that the displacement is my issue and I don't know how to fade out the displacement

[image]

Comment: Plug Gradient node or Z vector into Mix Shader Factor socket

Comment: I couldn't find a z vector, but I did try the gradient and ill figure out how to rotate it to gradient in the right direction, but the gradient isn't fading away completely to the solid color. The droplets are still 50% on the left and 100%on the right. https://ibb.co/yWwqqbN

Comment: You can get a Z vector by connecting the texture coordinate (use "Object" or "Generated", not UV) to a Separate XYZ node and taking the Z component. Also, place a ColorRamp before the mix factor (of the Mix Shader Node) to give stronger control over the cutoffs.

Comment: I changed the solid color to blue, so you could see the different materials. But you can see that the gradient isn't fading out completely away from the water drops. The drops are still visible into the blue. Here are my screenshots. https://ibb.co/nz1gCVZ  https://ibb.co/zRbKrxL

Comment: I think I found the issue, and I still don't know how to make it gradient. But I just realized the displacement is my issue because it's connected into the material output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Doesn't matter if you need to mix two shaders or to displace.
If you want to fade from floor to wall you have to mix them by gradient plugged into *Factor* of *Mix_* node.*

---

In case of Displace (or Normal) map you use *Mix RGB* node (in case of shaders you use *Mix Shaders*).

The fastest way to get **gradient** for this is not *Gradient Texture* node (as you noticed for its tricky rotation) ... but you can use *Texture Coordinate* node like type *Generated* and *Separate XYZ*  node to get black&white gradient in some main axis direction. Usually it is Z axis, but here works also X since wall is in X direction (so use depth).

Use this gradient as **Factor** to mix WaterDroplet-Height image with single grey color (use color picker to grab neutral color from flat part of height image).

[image]

Comment: Cool !.. yes.. _Bump_ does the height -> normal, and not always very well. Fixed. Will delete comment.